# Regex to move character to end of string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to convert a weird text file format (I'm pretty sure it's a Clojure hashed map) to json to load into a pandas data frame. I have written a function that does this, but it solves the specific problem in 5 lines of code, and I cannot for the life of me figure out the regex to do it in one.

This is the version info for my python environment and packages I am using:
Python Version: 3.7.7
pandas Version: 1.1.0
json Version: 2.0.9
re Version: 2.2.1

Here is some sample data, and the function I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

data = '[{:lat 38.43222, :lon 27.146801, :name "Izmir", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and 
by Atanasiu", :year 1837} {:lat 36.80083, :lon 10.1799965, :name "Tunis", :source "Biraben, as 
digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1837} {:lat 30.076834, :lon 31.251078, :name "Kairo", 
:source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1841} {:lat 32.116657, :lon 
20.066666, :name "Benghazi", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1856} 
{:lat 32.116657, :lon 20.066666, :name "Benghazi", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by 
Atanasiu", :year 1857} {:lat 33.88694, :lon 35.513046, :name "Beyrouth", :source "Biraben, as 
digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1859} {:lat 41.14995, :lon -8.6102295, :name "Porto", 
:source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1899} {:lat 41.14995, :lon 
-8.6102295, :name "Porto", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1900}]'

def clojure_to_json(clojure_text):
    # The pattern is wrap the words in quotes and move the colon after the closed quotation marks
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace('{:lat', '{"lat":')
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace(':lon', '"lon":')
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace(':name', '"name":')
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace(':year', '"year":')
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace(':source', '"source":')
    clojure_text = clojure_text.replace('} {', '} , {')
    return clojure_text



json_data = json.loads(clojure_to_json(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
print(df)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `p = re.compile(r':(\w+)\b'); s = p.sub(r'"\1":', data)`

Answer (score 0):

A single regexp, but not as concise as @Justin in the question's comments :

```py
import re

data = """\
[{:lat 38.43222, :lon 27.146801, :name "Izmir", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and \
by Atanasiu", :year 1837} {:lat 36.80083, :lon 10.1799965, :name "Tunis", :source "Biraben, as \
digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1837} {:lat 30.076834, :lon 31.251078, :name "Kairo", \
:source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1841} {:lat 32.116657, :lon \
20.066666, :name "Benghazi", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1856} \
{:lat 32.116657, :lon 20.066666, :name "Benghazi", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by \
Atanasiu", :year 1857} {:lat 33.88694, :lon 35.513046, :name "Beyrouth", :source "Biraben, as \
digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1859} {:lat 41.14995, :lon -8.6102295, :name "Porto", \
:source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1899} {:lat 41.14995, :lon \
-8.6102295, :name "Porto", :source "Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu", :year 1900}]\
"""
# I copy-pasted your code from SO and it added unwanted newlines, my version is paste-safe

pattern = re.compile(
    r"""
    \{
    :lat\ (?P<lat>(?:-)?\d+.\d+),
    \ 
    :lon\ (?P<lon>(?:-)?\d+.\d+),
    \ 
    :name\ "(?P<name>[^"]+)",
    \ 
    :source\ "(?P<source>[^"]+)",
    \ 
    :year\ (?P<year>\d+)
    \}
    """
    , re.VERBOSE)


def clojure_to_json(clojure_text):
    return [
        {
            key: match.group(index)
            for key, index in pattern.groupindex.items()
        }
        for match in pattern.finditer(clojure_text)
    ]


result = clojure_to_json(data)
print(result)
```

gives the expected JSON :

```json
[{'lat': '38.43222', 'lon': '27.146801', 'name': 'Izmir', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1837'}, {'lat': '36.80083', 'lon': '10.1799965', 'name': 'Tunis', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1837'}, {'lat': '30.076834', 'lon': '31.251078', 'name': 'Kairo', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1841'}, {'lat': '32.116657', 'lon': '20.066666', 'name': 'Benghazi', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1856'}, {'lat': '32.116657', 'lon': '20.066666', 'name': 'Benghazi', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1857'}, {'lat': '33.88694', 'lon': '35.513046', 'name': 'Beyrouth', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1859'}, {'lat': '41.14995', 'lon': '-8.6102295', 'name': 'Porto', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1899'}, {'lat': '41.14995', 'lon': '-8.6102295', 'name': 'Porto', 'source': 'Biraben, as digitized by Buntgen and by Atanasiu', 'year': '1900'}]
```